# Why am I getting all models of the user on click instead of the one clicked model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

On click on the one model from the collection im getting all models in the console of that user instead of the clicked one. Can anyone help me?

App.js

in App.js in sending models to another view to make a unique view for every model

```
var App = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() 
    {
            this.collection = new Documents();
            console.log("this.collection init", this.collection);
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.render);
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.renderSidebarModels);
    },

    renderSidebarModels: function() 
    {
            console.log("renderSidebarModels SYNC", this.collection);

            for(var i=0; i<this.collection.length; i++)
            {
                    console.log(this.collection.models);
                    this.sidebar = new SidebarView({model: this.collection.models[i]});
            }                      
    },

    $( document ).ready(function() {
       console.log( "ready!" );
       var app = new App();
    });
```

SidebarView.js

in SidebarView.js im getting all the model from the collection. When i click on the button with id #titles im getting all models of that user and not just the clicked model on this.model.

```
var SidebarView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el : this.$("#sidebar"),

        template: _.template(this.$('#sidebar-template').html()),

        events: 
        {
                "click #titles": "open",
        },

        initialize: function() 
        {
                console.log("sidebarView.initialize", this.model);
                this.render();
        },

        render: function() 
        {

                this.$el.append(this.template({ users: this.model }));
                //console.log(this.model);
                //return this;
        },

        open: function(e) 
        {
                console.log("open.sidebarView", this.model);  
        },  

})
```

Comment: What is `this` when you `el : this.$("#sidebar")`? You're better off not doing that sort of thing anyway, let each view create/own/destroy its own `el` then let the caller place that `el` in a container it owns; also, you're better off avoiding id-selectors for events due to their uniqueness. You'll have fewer event problems if you do those two things.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is not the cleanest way to initialize the model view, because you are **not** initializing one view per model, but the way you are assign the view to a model is to traverse the collection of models, and assigning each collection item to a specific view. This approach is cumbersome leading to performance hit and also cause a lot of extra code to be written in views.

The best approach is to use **one view per model**, which means each model in our collection has it’s own view object to render that mode’s data. This does not remove the need to have a View object that iterates the collection and populates the list, though. It only moves the implementation for each individual model down to a View for that Model. By this approach each view holds a direct reference to their model.

Something like this:

```
var App = Backbone.View.extend({    

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new Documents();
        console.log("this.collection init", this.collection);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.render);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.renderSidebarModels);
    },

    renderSidebarModels: function(item) {
        this.collection.models.each(function(item) {
            var sidebarView = new DealerView({                    
                model : item
            }, this);

            sidebarView.render();
            _this.$el.append(sidebarView.$el);
        });
    }
});
```

Using your approach one way to get the clicked item is to use the data attribute in place:

```
open: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(e.currentTarget).data("id");
    var item = this.collection.get(id);
    console.log(item);
},
```

But as i said this solution is not the best one we’re forced to look up the model based on the id of the model.

Read this article for a better understanding: https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/10/11/backbone-js-getting-the-model-for-a-clicked-element/

Comment: You forgot to initialize `_this` inside your your `each`. You'd be better off with `this.collection.each(function(item) { ... }, this)` anyway.

Comment: It didn't helped me :(

Comment: @lorenos what didn't helped? I gave you only an idea, it does not means, that the provided code per se should work. Until we don't have a full overview about the code, it's hard to provide a full working code.